# unable load jquery orgchart in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, jquery

I am trying to create an Org chart using Jquery like the below link in LWC

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Create-An-Editable-Organization-Chart-with-jQuery-orgChart-Plugin/

I am able to get all the scripts loaded in LWC , but the chart is not visible

below is my

### HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="orgChartContainer">
        Test
        <div class="orgChart"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

### JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import orgChart from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jOrgchart';
import orgChartss from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JOrgCss';
import jOrgjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/jOrgjs';

export default class Dorgchart extends LightningElement {
    error;
    chart;
    initialized = false;

    connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, orgChart).then(() => {
            console.log("jQuery loaded."),
                loadStyle(this, orgChartss).then(() => {
                    console.log("Orgchart css loaded"),
                        loadScript(this, jOrgjs).then(() => {
                            console.log("jQuery Org loaded.")
                            this.callChart();
                        }).catch(b => {
                            console.log("jQuery Org  not loaded.")
                        })
                }).catch(a => {
                    console.log("JQuery was not loaded. error is " + a)
                })
        }).catch(a => {
            console.log("jQuery loading was failed.")
        })])
    }

    callChart() {

        var testData = [
            { id: 1, name: 'My Organization', parent: 0 },
            { id: 2, name: 'CEO Office', parent: 1 },
            { id: 3, name: 'Division 1', parent: 1 },
            { id: 4, name: 'Division 2', parent: 1 },
            { id: 6, name: 'Division 3', parent: 1 },
            { id: 7, name: 'Division 4', parent: 1 },
            { id: 8, name: 'Division 5', parent: 1 },
            { id: 5, name: 'Sub Division', parent: 3 },

        ];
        $(function () {
            var org_chart = $('#orgChart').orgChart({
                data: testData,
                showControls: true,
                allowEdit: true,
                onAddNode: function (node) {
                    log('Created new node on node ' + node.data.id);
                    org_chart.newNode(node.data.id);
                },
                onDeleteNode: function (node) {
                    log('Deleted node ' + node.data.id);
                    org_chart.deleteNode(node.data.id);
                },
                onClickNode: function (node) {
                    log('Clicked node ' + node.data.id);
                }

            });
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you inspect the page to make sure the chart is inserted in the DOM? could it be a height issue?

Comment: i have attached a screenshot .. i have tried increasing the height , but no luck . i am also seeing some css error in console

Comment: please inspect the DOM

Comment: checked .. didnt find anything..

Comment: are you sure that `$('#orgChart')` is properly getting the element you are expecting it to?

Comment: checked. i think its empty..I have attached a screenshot

Comment: [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work)

Comment: Using .. this.template.querySelector('.orgChart').. I am getting undefined error..

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you need to review in your code.

For starters, you need to [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_dom_work) by using template.querySelector , secondly, you need to read how to [Use Third-Party JavaScript Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library) and use the lwc:dom="manual" directive in order to be able to append dom to an element.

Additionally, I would recommend avoiding using Jquery to access the DOM.